# Is it a good practice to give "id" for a dojo widget?

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

I'm using dojo 1.9 for my projects. I have been following an approach where I give "id" fo each dijits that I use. For ex:

```
var cp = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({\
 id:"myContentPane",
content:"Test"
});
```

is it a good practice to assign an id?
Reason I do
For ex, if I want to reload the cp with a new content, I check to see (by id) if the cp is already created or not. If yes, I just set the content and if not I create it. So above code gets changed to

```
if(!dijit.byId("myContentPane"){
var cp = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({\
 id:"myContentPane",
content:"Test"
});
}else{
dijit.byId("myContentPane").set("content","new content");
}
```

so I use id to check if the dijit is already created or not. Very rarely, I use the id to destroy the dijit.

Regards,
Manju

Answer (score 1):

That is a very personal choice.
However, by experience, on complex single page applications made of of multiple independent dojo modules IDs are very brittle.
On the project I am working, I completely banned them and instead I rely on attachpoints, class properties and widget api.

In your exemple, I assume the `var cp = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({` to be in a widget.
So I would do:

`_setContentAttr: function(content) {
    if(!this._contentPane) {
      this._contentPane = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({content: content});
    } else {
      this._contentPane.set('content', content);
    }
}`

This way I never rely on ID.

Conclusion is: **it depends on your project and its complexity.**

- On simple projects, yeah why not using IDs.
- On complex one, it's getting brittle and you'd better not.

BTW, as Dojo 1.9 use AMD, you should also avoid using "dijit.layout.ContentPane" and rather use the variable:

`require(["dijit/layout/ContentPane"], function(ContentPane){
    var cp = new ContentPane();
});`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I liked it. By the way, how would you handle if you have multiple contentPane ex: TabContainer having more than one. In my case, I have a tabcontainer which has around 12 content panes

Comment: You can store them in an array, on in a hashmap. They probably all have a functional meaning, so you could have something like ```{ user: CP1, settings: CP2, notifications: CP3}```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is always a good idea to identify your widgets by an unique a  reason is:

- You can retrieve your widget using `dijit/registry` in a easy and concise way without querying the DOM.

Example of usage:

```
require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry){
    var widget = registry.byNode(domNode);
});
```

Comment: more or less this is how I access my dijits today. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @ManjunathaMuniyappa hi, if you found my answer useful please do not forget to accept my answer clicking the tick and up arrow icon on its left side :). Thanks